# Unexplained declarations commands JDBC

Tags: java, android

Could someone explain to these 3 things which I can not understand? what they are and what they do?

```
 Connection co = null;
 Statement st = null;
```

and

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy ran = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(ran);
```

Comment: I have removed the jdbc tag, because this doesn't really have to do with JDBC, except that you show a declaration of variables with a null initialization where the type just happens to be a type from the `java.sql` package. That is basic Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declarations of `co` and `st` are just declarations.  They don't "do" anything apart from declare variables and initialize them to `null`.  This is very basic Java stuff.

`StictMode` is an facility for enabling some extra error checking in Android.  In this case `StrictMode` statements are actually removing all existing thread policy checks enabled by a previous `setThreadPolicy` call.  (That is what `permitAll()` means.)

For more details, refer to the docs:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder.html

---

> but what is connection and statement ?

They are (presumably) classes / interfaces for objects that represent 1) a connection to a database and 2) an (SQL) statement.  For more details:

1. Find the *full* classnames for those classes.  Hint: look at the `import` statements.
2. Read the respective class documentation.  Hint: if you cannot find the documentation for an Android class any other way, Google will find it.
3. Look how the variables are used in the code that you are looking at.

I / we cannot be more specific than that without seeing the `import` statements.

Comment: but what is connection and statement ?

Comment: @forschool Those are the type of the declaration. That is the basics of Java.

Comment: they are not declaration, they are interface but i dont know what they doing

Comment: @forschool - Please don't contradict people who **know** what they are talking about.  Those are *variable declarations*, and as I said, a Java variable declaration does not do anything.  If you want to k now what objects that implement those interfaces do (*which is NOT what you asked in your question!!*) then find and read the documentation for the interfaces

Comment: last question and i click accept answer, what mean "policy" ? i know what is thread, but 'policy' ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked to?  If that didn't help, then read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern,  And maybe the dictionary definition of policy (though the software meaning is only loosely related)

Comment: poorly explained, documentation are not for beginners